# Is it possible to invoke change_table from command line with ActiveRecord migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is possible to invoke a create_table syntax in a migration from command line by specifying the keyword 'Create' in the migration name:

```
rails g migration CreateMyTables name:string
```

This will create a migration with the following content:

```
class CreateMyTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_tables do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to accomplish the same but with the 'Change' keyword. So from the command line I would run:

```
rails g migration ChangeMyTables user:references
```

This is what I got:

```
class ChangeMyTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

This is what I would expect:

```
class ChangeMyTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :my_tables do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to add the reference column from command line:

```
rails g migration AddUserToMyTable user:references
```

**Note**: to add the column to the table we use the convention `Add[column]To[table]` for renaming the migration.

The result will be similar to:

```
class AddUserToMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :my_tables, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**Note:** `foreign_key: true` will create the index for you.

Learn more about [add_reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).

Comment: Yes, I am already aware of Add[column]To[table] syntax. My question is about if there is a Change[Table] syntax.

Comment: There are only naming conventions for create, delete, add and remove